# ErrorException (E_ERROR) rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given '

Tags: php, laravel

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given '

I am trying to display data from two tables and am getting the above error message, can somebody help translate this error message?

Here is the Controller

```
public function index()
{
  $maintenances = DB::table('tenants')->select('tenants.lastname','tenants.firstname','maintenances.m_status','tenants.designation',      'maintenances.description','maintenances.building_section','maintenances.category','maintenances.reported_date')
        ->join('maintenances','maintenances.tenants_id','=','tenants.id')
        ->get();
    //dd($maintenances);
    return view('agent/maintenance_list', compact('maintenances', 'assetTenants', 'tenants'));
}
```

And view

```
@foreach($maintenances as $maintenance)
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="checkbox-custom">
                    <input id="product-01" type="checkbox" value="01">
                    <label for="product-01" class="pl-0">&nbsp;</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->designation }} {{ $maintenance->firstname }} {{ $maintenance->lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->category }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->building_section }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->description }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->reported_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->m_status }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div role="group" aria-label="Basic example" class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <a href="{{ url('agent/edit_maintenance', $maintenance }}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
```

With the route

```
Route::get('maintenance_list', 'MaintenanceController@index')->name('/maintenance_list');
```

Comment: Indeed, we can't magically read your code from a distance. That'ts not how it works. 

Include your code snippets, error messages. Show us what you got, what did you try already?

Comment: In other words, take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicate that something is route with your url, in this case from the view. To solve this problem, this code

```
<a href="{{ url('agent/edit_maintenance', $maintenance }}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>
```

as to change to

```
<a href="{{ url('agent/edit_maintenance/'. $maintenance->id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>
```